# Is it possible to nest a proxy within C# layout with YARP?

Tags: next.js, proxy, single-page-application, ms-yarp

I am working on a proof of concept for a C# backend that proxies the UI from another server (NextJS) to the client's browser. However, I don't just want the proxy to take over the browser. I want something like the layouts in MVC where I can set up a navbar in the C# app and underneath that display the proxied content.

From what I can tell reading the YARP docs it doesn't seem like there is a way to take control of the proxy outside of the regular setup.

The proof of concept is intended to allow us to incrementally upgrade our UI by having specific pages be proxied but still display the layouts we already have setup in our MVC app. An ideal API would be a way from within a layout to render a section as proxied content.

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to this?

Comment: I did not :/, we ultimately just decided to build the whole thing in the NextJs app which didn't allow for incremental take over like I would've liked. Instead we setup used YARP to proxy specific routes and upgraded an entire route at a time.